# Unable to locate credentials celery

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, celery, celerybeat

hi i am using celery to schedule the tasks and run to read the data from the s3 files , but i am getting the error like **Unable to locate credentials** , but the same code is working fine with the **local environement** , when we deployed the code in the **production(EC2)** i am getting above error , and **without using the celery** i am able to connect the s3 and able to read the files.

the packages i  have used

```
boto3                     1.13.13
botocore                  1.16.13
celery                    4.4.4
```

both credentials are placed in same location like ~/.aws

can any one help

Comment: Does your EC2 have any IAM Role attached to it?

Comment: yes it has,  and i am able to access the files outside of celery , like i am running the code with out adding the @periodic_task decorator

Answer (score 0):

in the dev environment we have multiple users like our code is running on **user1** and i have give user name in  configured **celery.conf** files of **supervisor** is **user2** so that's why it is not not finding

Comment: will you please look at my question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73428421/when-celery-worker-is-started-it-throws-botocore-exceptions-nocredentialserror